# Simple Authentication server for kvm/libvitt

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have a single server running Ubuntu 20.04LTS for use by my grad students and by my 3rd year OS students. Amongst other things it runs kvm. I'm looking for a simple Authentication server that will let me give student access to control their virtual machines and only their virtual machines. They need to be able to start, stop, make several snapshots (linear in nature) and revert to the latest snapshot. I've looked at the list at https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Management_Tools. They are either defunct, no user differentiation like virsh, bare metal hypervisors, or overkill (i.e. over complicated) designed to manage multiple servers (e.g. oVirt, OpenNebula). Right now, I'm looking at a simple C setuid program that does exec system calls to wrap virsh, but I'd prefer something a bit more mature if it exists.

Comment: Throw libvirt. Use Proxmox VE. That said, software recommendations here are offtopic.

Comment: So where does one ask then? Anyways, Promox VE is a bare metal hypervisor and the server is used for things other than just virtual machines.

Comment: It is much better to use it only for virtual machines then. You can, for example, move all the former server tasks into dedicated virtual machine, amongst others, and use the bare metal solely for hypervisor. This is the good business practice actually. That said, Proxmox VE essentially is a Debian with a bunch of special packages, so in their official manuals they suggested the possibility to run additional tasks on the host, even the GUI.

Comment: To my knowledge libvirt itself doesn't have a developed ACL and permission system. It seems it relies to upper layers to do such tasks instead. So even if you stay with libvirt you'll eventually move from naked libvirt to some system that incorporates it as the virtualization management layer and provides essential permission management, and such a system will likely require that the host doesn't run any other tasks besides virtualization.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. However I'm not the full owner of the system, and moving other tasks into a dedicated VM is not my call, some of the research users require access to the bare metal. I realize that libvirt doesn't have a developed ACL, so I was hoping for something that was oVirt light? oVirt has sort of the ideas that I want, and even has documentation on how to run on a single machine. But it can't manage local storage, (the machine has to serve itself over NFS), and every time we've tried to use it, we run into roadblocks where it really seems to be optimized for running a cluster.